# How to make a python module function callable just by importing the module

Tags: python, module, packaging

Sounds trivial, but I'm a beginner.
I want to package a project "project", that includes a python file "pyfile", that includes a function "func".
Problem is that even though I include a **init**.py in this way:

```py
project
    |-pyfile.py
    |-__init__.py
```

I still need to call the function by

```py
from project import pyfile
pyfile.func()
```

How do I make the function callable just by

```py
import project
project.func()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add

```
from pyfile import *
```

to `project/__init__.py`

and

```
import project
project.func()
```

will work

Comment: That's genius! Thanks!